# Create a title block around a figure in R similar looking to autocad drawing titleblocks

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have created ggplot figures in R and I would like to throw a title block around these figures similar to one's that you would see in Autocad drawings.

I have searched high and low, and have not been able to find any information on how to go about doing this, if it is even possible.

Seems like a simple thing to do - create a black frame around the figure, and titleblocks at the bottom, which are just a series of rectangles; however, it does not look like R has a library that can do this, or the tools (e.g. create figure and paste into a title block frame).

I have hundreds of figures, so no I don't want to paste this figures by hand into a title block pdf.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add one example picture to show the output you would like to get?

Comment: The packages gridExtra and cowplot can be used to make complex graph arrangements (e.g. put multiple graphs, or a graph and a table, into one object, add images to graphs). I can't answer your question without knowing what you want your plots to look like, but I'd start by taking a look at the documentation for those packages

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

here's a possible strategy

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(1,1) + theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = 'black'))
border <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(lwd=2,fill=NA))
pl <- Map(function(p, i) arrangeGrob(p, bottom=sprintf("(%s)",i), vp=viewport(width=0.9, height=0.9)), list(p,p,p), letters[1:3])
g <- arrangeGrob(grobs = pl, layout_matrix=matrix(c(1,1,2,2,NA,3,3,NA),2,4,T))

g <- gtable_add_grob(g, border, 1, 1, nrow(g), ncol(g), Inf)
g <- gtable_add_rows(g, unit(2,"lines"))

gl <- lapply(c("", "Project No", "Results for something", "Fig 5", "Md-123"), 
             function(x) grobTree(border, textGrob(label = x)))
banner <- arrangeGrob(grobs=gl, layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,2,3,4),
                                              c(1,5,3,4)), 
                      widths=c(1,2,5,2))

g <- gtable_add_grob(g, banner, nrow(g), 1, nrow(g), ncol(g), Inf)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRR5Q.png)